# Iterating through object's properties lists things in the prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to make a "copy" function and add it to the object's prototype. I planned to recursively typecheck and assign properties to a new object and then return the object... But, there seems to be a problem, see this snippet of code:

```
Object.prototype.copy = function()
{
    for (prop in this)
    {
        console.log(prop); //Logs copy (the function)!!!
    }
}

x = {"a": 1};
y = x.copy();
```

As I've pointed out in the comment, I found this very weird behavior, but why is this happening? The copy function should be in `Object.prototype`, not in the instanced object itself! How do I fix it? Can I just set `this.copy = undefined`, and still rely on `Object.prototype.copy`?

This is the full code sample, as requested:

```
Object.prototype.copy = function()
{
    var object = this; //The object we are copying.
    var newObject = {}; //The object we will return.

    //Cycle through the properties of the object we are creating, copy them recursively.
    for (prop in object)
    {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, prop) || object[prop] == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (prop == "copy")
        {
            console.log("Well, blah."); //This never prints!
        }

        if (typeof(object[prop]) == "object" && !(object[prop] instanceof Array)) //If the object's property is another object...
        {
            newObject[prop] = object[prop].copy(); //Set the copy of it to the new object as well.
            console.log("1 --- " + prop); //This prints copy - two times! That defies logic!
        }
        else if (typeof(object[prop]) == "object") //If it's an array...
        {
            newObject[prop] = object[prop].slice(); //Do it in a nicer fashion.
            console.log("2 --- " + prop);
        }
        else //You're safe to copy it.
        {
            newObject[prop] = object[prop];
            console.log("3 --- " + prop + " --- " + object[prop]);
        }
    }

    return newObject;
}
```

Comment: If you are wanting to do a generic deep object copy, and you're using jQuery, you can use `var obj2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj1);`

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, and I want to code it myself.

Comment: Then @Pointy's answer is the way to go: `for (prop in this) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, prop)) { ... }`

Comment: ah - I see it - you forgot to declare "prop" with a `var` statement!

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I had to do that... I see what's the problem now, it was global and the recursive functions were changing the prop's value for the upper ones, right?

Comment: @Pointy, and one more thing, is there a way to fix circular reference in these kinds of functions?

Comment: If you don't use `var` the variable is **global** - weird thing about JavaScript.  Circular references are kind-of challenging, esp. in JavaScript.  The problem is that you basically need to keep track of all the objects you've "seen" as you thread your way through the relationships. That's problematic because there's no good way to hash a **reference value** for an object. Thus, you have to simply check a list, and that obviously gets expensive if you're doing a lot of copying of large complicated objects.

Comment: So basically, add every visited object to an array, each time check the array, if the object I'm currently on is in there, just put a reference to that object, right? That will probably suck to implement...

Comment: @Bane: A common principle held is to not extend `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties. It forces you to use `hasOwnProperty` in every iteration of every object that is enumerated everywhere in code. Also, you'll never be able reliably have an object with the property `"copy"` on it. And this is just the start. There are so many downsides, that it's widely considered an unsafe practice. You'd do better to create a function, and place it on `Object`. `Object.copy = function(obj) { /* copy the object */ });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method called "hasOwnProperty" that you can use:

```
 if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { ... }
```

If the function returns `true` the it's a "direct" property on the object.

If you fear that the "hasOwnProperty" method may be borked, you can do this:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, prop)) { ... }
```

instead.

Newer versions of JavaScript have fancier ways of examining and controlling objects.

*edit* — also your updated code involves a problem that'll bite due to the nested calls to "copy": you didn't declare "prop" with `var`, so after the call to copy an object, the value of "prop" will have changed! (Every call to "copy" shares the same variable, in other words.)

Comment: I don't get it, what am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: @Bane Inside your `for` loop, only log (or whatever) those values of "prop" for which the function returns `true`.

Comment: Oh yeah, silly me, it works now, thanks! But how and why is that happening?

Comment: Well @Bane that's just how the `for ... in` loop works. It includes properties that are directly on the object as well as those it inherits.

Comment: Huh, OK. But I have problem again, I'll try that second method of yours... Yep, even that gives me copy again... Although I'm using the full function code now, on some of my game objects, so the problem must be there...

Comment: Perhaps you could add the actual code (or a bigger sample); checking "hasOwnProperty()" works in every case I know of.

Comment: I just added the whole function, it's not lengthy at all, would you please check it out?